# Customize yaxis

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

Is it possible to have an axis “break” or spaced unevenly ? For instance, suppose I have data grouped around y=[0,100] and some outliers, e.g. 500, 1000 etc.
 Displaying from 0-1000 will hide the details.
Can I show data from y=0-100 and then y=800-1000 and have the axis ticks etc break in between?
i've tried enumerated tickvals and ticktext, but it seems not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like you want using subplots, but it is a really ugly solution.

Code:

```
# import all the necessaries libraries
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import tools

# specify traces
trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[500, 1100, 1500],
    xaxis='x1',
    yaxis='y1')
trace2 = go.Bar(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[500, 1100, 1500],
    xaxis='x2',
    yaxis='y2')
trace3 = go.Bar(
    x=[1, 2, 3],
    y=[500, 1100, 1500],
    xaxis='x3',
    yaxis='y3')

# create data (list with traces)
data = [trace1, trace2, trace3]

# Specify layout
layout = go.Layout(
    height=600, width=600,
    # Select each yaxis and manually set domain (where on screen it will place)
    yaxis1=dict(range=[400, 600], domain=[0, 0.25]),
    yaxis2=dict(range=[1000, 1200], domain=[0.35, 0.60]),
    yaxis3=dict(range=[1400, 1600], domain=[0.70, 0.95])
    )

# Create figure
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

# Plot the plot
pyo.plot(fig, filename='try-axis-plot.html')
```

Output:

[image: You see that?]

And after googling I decided, that "break" axis in `plotly` is not allowed, as described [here](https://community.plot.ly/t/make-tick-break-on-axis/11856)